# Suggestions for a hashcode of a Card object in a poker game?

Tags: java, hashcode

How is the hashcode computed for a card object which consists of enum suit and enum rank ?

Comment: The space of the cards domain ( 52 ) is small enough to fit into an `enum` it self.

Comment: @Jarrod: true enough, but the boss/teacher's requirements trump all. :)

Comment: Since you're new, I would like you to point that - people do spent their time to answer questions, it will be good if you consider to accept the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Eclipse, it can generate a "good enough" `hashCode()` implementation for you:

[image: context menu screenshot]

```
public class Card
{
    private Suit suit;
    private Rank rank;

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((rank == null) ? 0 : rank.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((suit == null) ? 0 : suit.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof Card)) return false;
        Card other = (Card) obj;
        if (rank != other.rank) return false;
        if (suit != other.suit) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I can only imagine that NetBeans, IntelliJ IDEA, etc., can do this as well.

---

That said, since the domain is small, this implementation will work equally well (I think...):

```
public int hashCode()
{
    int rankHash = ((rank == null) ? 0 : (1+rank.ordinal()));
    int suitHash = ((suit == null) ? 0 : (1+suit.ordinal()));
    return rankHash + 31*suitHash;
}
```

This assumes that `Rank` ordinals are `0-12` inclusive and `Suit` ordinals are `0-3` inclusive. Note that most of the ugliness there comes from the null checks. If the values can never be null, then:

```
public int hashCode()
{
    return rank.ordinal() + 31*suit.ordinal();
}
```

Comment: Deleting my answer - as yours is more thorough.

Answer (score 3):

With so little value space (is it 13 times 4?) it makes no sense to assign any two cards the same hash-code. So it's completely up to you, but something like:

```
A spades = 1
K spades = 2
....
A clubs = 21
K clubs = 22
....
```

should be OK.

Generally it makes sense to define a hashcode if there are really huge numbers of possible values (like every possible `String` value or every possible list of numbers `List<Number>`) and to have them limited to (projected into) a limited space of hashcode values. If we are talking about  `hashCode()` as defined by `java.lang.Object` API then the 'limited space of hashcode values' has to fit into `int` type (integers).

Answer (score 2):

The space of the cards domain ( 52 ) is small enough to fit into an `enum` it self. And that would give you a natural primary key for identification as well, since `hashCode` should be a unique identifier for the internal state of the object as well.

Here is some pseudo Java code to give you an idea:

```
public enum Suit
    HEART, CLUB, SPADE, DIAMOND

public enum Rank
    TWO, THREE, FOUR ... KING, QUEEN, ACE

public enum Card
   private final Suit suit;
   private final Rank rank;
   private Card(final Suit s, final Rank r);

   ACE_HEARTS(ACE,HEART), TWO_HEARTS(TWO,HEART), ... KING_DIAMONDS(KING, DIAMOND);

   public int hashCode() { return this.ordinal; )
```

Comment: That's simple and to the point (now I have only 2 votes left today -- which I hate!).